# Cosimulation Error on Advanced Design System

Tags: transistors, pcb, simulation, ads

I want to use [BLF2425M9LS140](https://www.ampleon.com/products/rf-energy/2.45-ghz-transistors/BLF2425M9LS140.html), Power LDMOS transistor, to do cosimulation on ADS. I have got transistor's PCB design from its site and have done required procedure but when I try to convert layout to schematic model then simulate it, I get following error:

[image: error]

I_0 is the name of the PCB layout and I cannot see the vendor simulation component:[image: Palette]

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to include the vendor simulation component? This is an example from when i did some simulations with some Infineon transistors.. This had to be in the schematic to work.

[image: inf]

Comment: I edited the question @Linkyyy

Comment: @AldrichTaylor: Ok, well i just added the library to ADS and tested it, it doesn't give me any errors. How did you add the library? DesignKits -> Manage favorite design kits -> Add zipped design kit.. ?

Comment: I did the same thing @Linkyyy but unfortunately it gives an error. Can there be any other reason? Because I also converted layout to symbol to simulate on schematic. Can this problem be related to that process?

Comment: @AldrichTaylor: Maybe. try creating a new project and simulation without the the layout and see if it works. I don't have any experience with it unfortunately.

Comment: I solved the problem. After creating emModel from layout sim, you should click emModel in choose view from simulation in schematics